# Entity Framework DbContext won't save data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to do simplest thing in EF, to save data record into database table.

Everything goes well, model gets created, added, and saved, but when I go to the table the is nothing...

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

This is my `DbContext`:

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AuthContext() : base("AuthContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TransferResponse> Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FailCounter> Fails { get; set; } 
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class FailCounter
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int FailCounterValue { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code for saving:

```
using(AuthContext dbcnt = new AuthContext())
{
    var userId = repo.FindByUserName(model.DeviceId);
    FailCounter failCount = new FailCounter();
    failCount.FailCounterValue = 1;
    failCount.UserId = userId.Id;
    dbcnt.Fails.Add(failCount);
    dbcnt.SaveChanges();
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password.");
}
```

I've used debugger and found nothing... userId is not null, so that line is not a problem. No exception, nothing, but then again database is empty.

Comment: By "going to the table" do you mean looking at it in VS via the database tools or selecting values in your code? If the first: Maybe you're just looking at the wrong database an EF is using a different `ConnectionString`.

Comment: @germi both... I've even look it from SQL Managment Studio... And during debugging I've checked if the values were correct, too :-/

Comment: Could your code be pointing to a 'test' database by mistake (for example, a (localdb)\v11.0 database)?

Comment: Run SQL Profiler to see what SQL statements are executed. What is the return value of SaveChanges? Are you using a transaction that didn't get commited?

Comment: @nemo_87 Just to be clear: If you try to select values from the database in your code after you saved something, you don't get anything either?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've just did, and it's been saving values all the time. First I've restarted SQL MS, than I've restarted VS, still nothing, after I've restarted my machine all data was there... Totally weird situation, but it works after all. Thanks guys!

Comment: Visual Studio "Pluralize Database names" -setting sometimes causes confusion with complex class names. I had a similar issue, the values were saved to a database that EF created again for each debug session and I was looking in to the wrong one.

Comment: Restarting anything won't help with code problems. It's not SQL Server or VS that's failing. What *did* you find in the profiler? What commands were executed? What database was targeted? If you see the succesful commands in the profiler the data is in the database - period. Either you are missing a transaction or looking at the wrong database

Comment: What is your connection string? Are you targeting LocalDB ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will update my post, just to show clearly what happened. Profiler showed data in the database.

Comment: Is your database initializer DropCreateAlways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead of `FailCounter failCount = new FailCounter();`

try it like that `FailCounter failCount = dbcnt.Fails.Create();`

Comment: well, nice if it works, but `Add` should do it also.